# How to list schemas of a specific database in Informix using SQL?

Tags: sql, database, informix

What is the query to get a list of schemas names in a specific database in Informix?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A schema belongs to a user. You can list all available users from [the  **sysusers** system catalog](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_077.htm) :

```
SELECT username FROM "informix".sysusers;
```

Since only `DBA`s and `Resource` privilieges allow a user to issue a [`CREATE SCHEMA` statement](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_0483.htm), we could restrict the query like :

```
SELECT username FROM "informix".sysusers WHERE usertype IN ('D', 'R');
```

---

Another solution is to list only users that actually have created tables ; for that, you can query [the  **systables** system catalog](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_072.htm) and list distinct owners.

```
SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM FROM "informix".systables
```

As commented by @JonathanLeffler, a user could have been granted `RESOURCE` privileges and have created a table, and then be 'demoted' to `CONNECT` privileges. The user would still own the table. Hence the second solution is the most accurate.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In Informix architecture, every product installation of Informix can have multiple instances, every instance can have multiple databases and each db can have multiple schemas right? I want the list of schemas for a specific database or user  (based on what you said)

Comment: @mor222 : yes... each user (may) have a single schema. These queries operate on database-level and should give you the result you expect.

Comment: So you mean every user can have only 0 or 1 schema? and the name of that schema is the same as the user's name?

Comment: @mor222 : yes, exactly. Check out the link to the **CREATE SCHEMA statement** that I put in my answer.

Comment: A user could have been granted RESOURCE privileges and create a table, and then be 'demoted' to CONNECT privileges.  The user would still own the table.  Also, it's possible for users not listed in SysUsers to own tables — witness "pokemon" and "pikachu" in the example in my answer.  Plus it's possible to grant privileges to PUBLIC so anyone can connect. Thus, selecting from SysUsers is wholly unreliable as a way of determining which names could be owners of schema objects. Searching through SysTables is much more reliable; that will list users who own tables and views — which is 99% accurate.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler : yes, I agree... I updated my answer to mention that explictly.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler  when I execute the second query, I get 3 owners: 

1) 12.10.xC8
2) 9.57C1 
3) informix

what are the first two owners? should I ignore them as the built-in owners?
By the way, how can I calculate schema max size and size using query?

Answer (score 3):

Schemas are not commonly used in Informix databases and have very little trackability within a database.  The CREATE SCHEMA notation is supported because it was part of SQL-89.  The AUTHORIZATION clause is used to determine the (default) 'owner' of the objects created with the CREATE SCHEMA statement.  There is nothing to stop a single user running the CREATE SCHEMA statement multiple times, either consecutively or at widely different times (in any given database within an Informix instance).

```
CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION "pokemon"
    CREATE TABLE gizmo (s SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, v VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL)
    CREATE TABLE widget(t SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, d DATETIME YEAR TO SECOND NOT NULL)
    ;

CREATE SCHEMA AUTHORIZATION "pokemon"
    CREATE TABLE object   (u SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, i INTEGER NOT NULL)
    CREATE TABLE "pikachu".complain (C SERIAL NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, v VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL)
    ;
```

After the CREATE SCHEMA statement executes, there is no way of tracking that either pair of these tables were created together as part of the same schema; there's no way to know that `"pikachu".complain` was part of a CREATE SCHEMA statement executed on behalf of `"pokemon"`.  There is no DROP SCHEMA statement that would necessitate such support.