# Is there any way to list all schema in informix (including the ones which donot have any tables and any privileges)?

Tags: informix

I am trying to fetch metadata in my application. For that, I need to list all schemas and their metadata in informix. I am not able to find any system table which will list all schemas (as in oracle).

I saw this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54507381/how-to-list-schemas-of-a-specific-database-in-informix-using-sql) but couldn't get desired result.
Have referred to informix's official website for [systables](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_072.htm) and [sysusers](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqlr.doc/ids_sqr_077.htm)

```
select username,usertype from sysusers;
```

-- fetches users or roles with database level privileges

```
select distinct owner from systables;
```

-- fetches schemas containing a database object.

Also, what exactly is present in `sysmaster` database's `systables` and `sysusers`? When to use them?

Comment: As pointed out by @JonathanLeffler in the answer you linked, there is no `schema` object in Informix. You can pretend to have schemas in Informix by getting a list of all object owners and present them as the schemas of a database.

Comment: @LuísMarques Thanks for your reply but what if a user/schema doesnot have any objects created? How should I list it? Is there any system table which stores information about all users and schemas? Also, can you/someone please clarify sysmaster?

Answer (score 2):

There is no actual schema object in an Informix database ( you cannot grant privileges on a schema ). There are various types of "objects" and each object has an owner. You could consider that the owner is the schema, if you really want to. Doing a simple search on the catalog tables on a newly created Informix ( version 14.10.FC1 ) database  we get:

```
SELECT
    t.tabname,
    c.colname
FROM
    systables AS t 
INNER JOIN 
    syscolumns AS c
ON 
    t.tabid = c.tabid
WHERE 
    c.colname = 'owner'
;


tabname  systables
tabname  sysindices
tabname  syssynonyms
tabname  syssyntable
tabname  sysconstraints
tabname  sysprocedures
tabname  sysopclstr
tabname  systriggers
tabname  sysobjstate
tabname  sysxtdtypes
tabname  syscasts
tabname  sysopclasses
tabname  sysaggregates
tabname  sysdomains
tabname  sysindexes
```

And there can be more, this was just a quick look at the catalog tables. So your schema information is spread over multiple catalogs.

About the sysmaster database, it is a database ( although a special one ) and therefore it has it's own catalogs tables, just like any other Informix database.